# Making function using 2x4 decoder and one or gate

Tags: logic-gates, decoder, boolean-algebra

I frankly don't understand how to make it. I try to make but, I think it's wrong. How can I make it ?
Function is: $$f(a,b,c) = ∑(0,1,2,3,7)$$

My trying:

[image]

In addition using 3x8 I make:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's shoud be a decoder and not Demux?

Comment: Yup. I'm sure that is decoder. @EugeneSh.

Comment: Then looks not possible to me. How can you make an output of decoder to be `c` as on the drawing?

Comment: Umm I know it is wrong. I've asked the questiong to get right answer.

Comment: @AskQuestion . Be clear. Is it 2X4 decoder or 3X8 ? Its a matter of seconds to use 3X8 but little harder using 2X4.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler "A little harder"? I think it is impossible, and (hopefully) I have proven it below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stated in the question looks to be impossible to solve. I will try to prove it here.
The function required is $$F=\bar{A}+ABC=\bar{A}+BC$$

First let's look at two different(and the only possible) configurations: 
1) The OR gate's output is connected to one of the `sel` inputs of the decoder. 
2) The OR gate's output is the function output.

The first configuration assuming two of the function inputs to be connected to the OR inputs, and the third connected to the decoder input (and might be connected to OR as well):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdtzGS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the 2-input OR variant the outputs are given as follows:

```
x   y   z   Y0  Y1  Y2  Y3
0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   1   1   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   1   0   0   0   1
```

As we can see neither of `Y` can be represented as SOP of 4. So this configuration won't work.
For the 3-input or variant:

```
x   y   z   Y0  Y1  Y2  Y3
0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   1   1   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   1   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   1   0   0   0   1
```

Only \$Y_3\$ is SOP of four, but it's obvious that the function is \$Y_3=x\$, and no assignment of the original variables to \$X,Y,Z\$ will make it the required function. 
As for the second approach, while the OR is connected to the Decoder outputs, there is only two inputs on the decoder, then the third one has to be connected to the OR itself. But then the output will be always `1` when that input is `1`. But, as can be seen from the truth table, there is at least one case for each input \$A,B,C\$ where it is `1`, but the output is `0`. Then this configuration doesn't work as well.

Comment: My instructor's solution is: http://i.imgur.com/xFRBT91.png what do you think ?

Comment: He is cheating. `a'` requires a `NOT` gate.

Comment: so even if we think it is a solution, can be it the right solution ?

Comment: It is right function. The decoder output is `BC`, and then it is OR-ed with `A'`, so the function is `A'+BC` as required.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Agree. I tried a dozen solutions (even active low gates didnt help) . I would say instructor used unfair means !